# Error after adding spring-data-jpa into gradle file?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have this dependencies in my gradle file.

```
dependencies {
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth')
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin')
implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.5'
implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.24'
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
implementation group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc', version: '6.0'
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
integrationTestCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
integrationTestCompile group: 'com.github.tomakehurst', name: 'wiremock', version: '2.1.6'
integrationTestCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
integrationTestCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.5'
integrationTestCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'
integrationTestCompile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'}
```

However after adding:

> implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

application does not start.

My whole gradle file is:

```html
buildscript {
 ext {
  springBootVersion = '2.0.7.RELEASE'
 }
 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
 }
}

plugins {
 id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
 id "io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok" version "1.14"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group = 'com.doruk'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {

 maven {
  url "http://nexus.internal/repository/maven-public/"
 }

 maven {
  url "http://nexus.internal/repository/maven-snapshots/"
 }

 maven {
  url "http://nexus.internal/repository/maven-releases/"
 }
 mavenCentral()
 jcenter()
}

ext {
 springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR2'
}

configurations {
 integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
 integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
 implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
 implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
 implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth')
 implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin')
 implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
 implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.5'
 implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'
 implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.24'
 implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
 implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
 implementation group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc', version: '6.0'
 compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
 testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 integrationTestCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 integrationTestCompile group: 'com.github.tomakehurst', name: 'wiremock', version: '2.1.6'
 integrationTestCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
 integrationTestCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.5'
 integrationTestCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'
 integrationTestCompile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
}

dependencyManagement {
 imports {
  mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
 }
}

sonarqube {
 properties {
  property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "$buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
 }
}

sourceSets {
 integrationTest {
  java {
   compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
   runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
   srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
  }
  resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
 }
}
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
sourceSets.integrationTest.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
 testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
 classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}


check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test

bootJar {
 mainClassName = "com.doruk.customer.Main"
}
```

It works perfecty without spring-boot-starter-jpa, however if add it, when i run it stuck in

> {"timestamp":"2018-12-24 03:00:31.400","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"com.doruk.customer.Main","message":"No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default","context":"default"}

I try to add specific version of dependency like:

> implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'

and it didnt worked.

I also tried to delete my whole .gradle folder, and download again.

Application fetch dependencies from nexus.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You must have one dpendency only. I noticed that you have added that dependecy.

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") //here
```

Then you shouldn't add it again.

Comment: I didnt add that dependency twice, my whole gradle post gives me error. If i extract implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') it run.

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer, why do you need that dependecy?

Comment: I am using for create Entity, which is necessary annotions in persistence api

Comment: Sure! but so why are you using reserved word implementation that is used in project on Android OS?

Comment: However even I dont add code to my project. It doesnt start, it stuck at start when I add jpa dependency in gradle. I mean I am not using  jpa currently.

Comment: Ok It is rare.. so could you please share on a repo?

Comment: I dont think this is the case. I mostly use implementation keyword, it works fine. However I tried and  still dont work with compile keyword.